# Nginx not proxying websockets (using socket.io and nodejs)

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, websocket, socket.io

I have a nodejs application running on port 8000 and the following nginx configs to proxy my requests (8800 for http and 8443 for https):

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;

    upstream node {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }


    server {
        listen               8800;
        access_log /usr/local/etc/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /usr/local/etc/nginx/error.log;
        rewrite_log on;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_pass http://node;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen               8443;
        ssl                  on;

        ssl_certificate      /usr/local/etc/nginx/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/etc/nginx/server.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

        access_log /usr/local/etc/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /usr/local/etc/nginx/error.log;
        rewrite_log on;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_pass http://node;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run my application at http://localhost:8800 and check Chrome Dev Tools, the websocket request (ws://localhost) returns a successful '101 Switching protocols'.  But the same request (wss://localhost) doesn't work when I run it on the https://localhost (with self certified SSL certs)

Also,  when I try to debug the request on nginx with

```
curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" http://localhost:8800/
```

or

```
 curl -i -N -k -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" https://localhost:8443/
```

the response is 502 Bad Gateway.

I am trying to figure out why nginx isn't proxying the request properly.

Comment: Have you looked in the nginx logfiles?

Comment: There's no log when a ws:// request is made when I access the application on the browser.  But when I run the curl command, I get 

"upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "localhost:8800"
20"

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/ this is a great tutorial about nginx & websockets !

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure what I did. Removed all nginx related files. Re-installed nginx and it worked like a charm.